# SOAP webservice Error:Response to preflight request does not pass access control check 'Access-Control-Access-Origin' using SOAPClient.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have consumed a SOAP webservice  in my application using SOAP client library.
Webservice runs properly if I execute my code in disable—secuity mode. But if I run my code without disabling the security mode  I am not able to run my webservice .

Controller which invokes SOAPClient.js

```js
function GetSoapResponse() {
  var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
  SOAPClient.invoke(url, "HelloWorld", pl, true, GetSoapResponse_callBack);
}

function GetSoapResponse_callBack(r, soapResponse) {
  if (soapResponse.xml) // IE
    alert(soapResponse.xml);
  else // MOZ
    alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(soapResponse));
}
```

SOAPClient.js

```js
/*****************************************************************************\

 Javascript "SOAP Client" library
 
\*****************************************************************************/

function SOAPClientParameters() {
 var _pl = new Array();
 this.add = function(name, value) {
  _pl[name] = value;
  return this;
 }
 this.toXml = function() {
  var xml = "";
  for ( var p in _pl) {
   switch (typeof (_pl[p])) {
   case "string":
   case "number":
   case "boolean":
   case "object":
    xml += "<" + p + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(_pl[p])
      + "</" + p + ">";
    break;
   default:
    break;
   }
  }
  return xml;
 }
}
SOAPClientParameters._serialize = function(o) {
 var s = "";
 switch (typeof (o)) {
 case "string":
  s += o.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g,
    "&gt;");
  break;
 case "number":
 case "boolean":
  s += o.toString();
  break;
 case "object":
  // Date
  if (o.constructor.toString().indexOf("function Date()") > -1) {

   var year = o.getFullYear().toString();
   var month = (o.getMonth() + 1).toString();
   month = (month.length == 1) ? "0" + month : month;
   var date = o.getDate().toString();
   date = (date.length == 1) ? "0" + date : date;
   var hours = o.getHours().toString();
   hours = (hours.length == 1) ? "0" + hours : hours;
   var minutes = o.getMinutes().toString();
   minutes = (minutes.length == 1) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
   var seconds = o.getSeconds().toString();
   seconds = (seconds.length == 1) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
   var milliseconds = o.getMilliseconds().toString();
   var tzminutes = Math.abs(o.getTimezoneOffset());
   var tzhours = 0;
   while (tzminutes >= 60) {
    tzhours++;
    tzminutes -= 60;
   }
   tzminutes = (tzminutes.toString().length == 1) ? "0"
     + tzminutes.toString() : tzminutes.toString();
   tzhours = (tzhours.toString().length == 1) ? "0"
     + tzhours.toString() : tzhours.toString();
   var timezone = ((o.getTimezoneOffset() < 0) ? "+" : "-") + tzhours
     + ":" + tzminutes;
   s += year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "T" + hours + ":" + minutes
     + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds + timezone;
  }
  // Array
  else if (o.constructor.toString().indexOf("function Array()") > -1) {
   for ( var p in o) {
    if (!isNaN(p)) // linear array
    {
     (/function\s+(\w*)\s*\(/ig).exec(o[p].constructor
       .toString());
     var type = RegExp.$1;
     switch (type) {
     case "":
      type = typeof (o[p]);
     case "String":
      type = "string";
      break;
     case "Number":
      type = "int";
      break;
     case "Boolean":
      type = "bool";
      break;
     case "Date":
      type = "DateTime";
      break;
     }
     s += "<" + type + ">"
       + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(o[p]) + "</"
       + type + ">"
    } else
     // associative array
     s += "<" + p + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(o[p])
       + "</" + p + ">"
   }
  }
  // Object or custom function
  else
   for ( var p in o)
    s += "<" + p + ">" + SOAPClientParameters._serialize(o[p])
      + "</" + p + ">";
  break;
 default:
  break; // throw new Error(500, "SOAPClientParameters: type '" + typeof(o) + "' is not supported");
 }
 return s;
}

function SOAPClient() {
}

SOAPClient.username = null;
SOAPClient.password = null;

SOAPClient.invoke = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback) {
 if (async)
  SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback);
 else
  return SOAPClient._loadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback);
}

// private: wsdl cache
SOAPClient_cacheWsdl = new Array();

// private: invoke async
SOAPClient._loadWsdl = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback) {
 // load from cache?
 debugger;
 var wsdl = SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url];
 if (wsdl + "" != "" && wsdl + "" != "undefined")
  return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async,
    callback, wsdl);
 // get wsdl
 var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
 xmlHttp.open("GET", url + "?wsdl", async);
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',"Fetch");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 
 if (async) {
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async,
      callback, xmlHttp);
  }
 }
 xmlHttp.send(null);
 if (!async)
  return SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl(url, method, parameters, async, callback,
    xmlHttp);
}
SOAPClient._onLoadWsdl = function(url, method, parameters, async, callback, req) {
 var wsdl = req.responseXML;
 SOAPClient_cacheWsdl[url] = wsdl; // save a copy in cache
 return SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest(url, method, parameters, async,
   callback, wsdl);
}
SOAPClient._sendSoapRequest = function(url, method, parameters, async,
  callback, wsdl) {
 // get namespace
 var ns = (wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"] + "" == "undefined") ? wsdl.documentElement.attributes
   .getNamedItem("targetNamespace").nodeValue
   : wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"].value;
 // build SOAP request
 var sr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + "<soap:Envelope "
   + "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
   + "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
   + "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
   + "<soap:Body>" + "<" + method + " xmlns=\"" + ns + "\">"
   + parameters.toXml() + "</" + method
   + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
 // send request
 var xmlHttp = SOAPClient._getXmlHttp();
 if (SOAPClient.userName && SOAPClient.password) {
  xmlHttp.open("POST", url, async, SOAPClient.userName,
    SOAPClient.password);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',"Fetch");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  // Some WS implementations (i.e. BEA WebLogic Server 10.0 JAX-WS) don't support Challenge/Response HTTP BASIC, so we send authorization headers in the first request
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "
    + SOAPClient._toBase64(SOAPClient.userName + ":"
      + SOAPClient.password));
 } else
  xmlHttp.open("POST", url, async);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',"Fetch");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 var soapaction = ((ns.lastIndexOf("/") != ns.length - 1) ? ns + "/" : ns)
   + method;
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapaction);
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 if (async) {
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, wsdl,
      xmlHttp);
  }
 }
 xmlHttp.send(sr);
 if (!async)
  return SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest(method, async, callback, wsdl,
    xmlHttp);
}

SOAPClient._onSendSoapRequest = function(method, async, callback, wsdl, req) {
 var o = null;
 var nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, method
   + "Result");
 if (nd.length == 0)
  nd = SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName(req.responseXML, "return"); // PHP web Service?
 if (nd.length == 0) {
  if (req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultcode").length > 0) {
   if (async || callback)
    o = new Error(
      500,
      req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   else
    throw new Error(
      500,
      req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faultstring")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }
 } else
  o = SOAPClient._soapresult2object(nd[0], wsdl);
 if (callback)
  callback(o, req.responseXML);
 if (!async)
  return o;
}
SOAPClient._soapresult2object = function(node, wsdl) {
 var wsdlTypes = SOAPClient._getTypesFromWsdl(wsdl);
 return SOAPClient._node2object(node, wsdlTypes);
}
SOAPClient._node2object = function(node, wsdlTypes) {
 // null node
 if (node == null)
  return null;
 // text node
 if (node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4)
  return SOAPClient._extractValue(node, wsdlTypes);
 // leaf node
 if (node.childNodes.length == 1
   && (node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 3 || node.childNodes[0].nodeType == 4))
  return SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[0], wsdlTypes);
 var isarray = SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.nodeName, wsdlTypes)
   .toLowerCase().indexOf("arrayof") != -1;
 // object node
 if (!isarray) {
  var obj = null;
  if (node.hasChildNodes())
   obj = new Object();
  for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
   var p = SOAPClient._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdlTypes);
   obj[node.childNodes[i].nodeName] = p;
  }
  return obj;
 }
 // list node
 else {
  // create node ref
  var l = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
   l[l.length] = SOAPClient
     ._node2object(node.childNodes[i], wsdlTypes);
  return l;
 }
 return null;
}
SOAPClient._extractValue = function(node, wsdlTypes) {
 var value = node.nodeValue;
 switch (SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl(node.parentNode.nodeName, wsdlTypes)
   .toLowerCase()) {
 default:
 case "s:string":
  return (value != null) ? value + "" : "";
 case "s:boolean":
  return value + "" == "true";
 case "s:int":
 case "s:long":
  return (value != null) ? parseInt(value + "", 10) : 0;
 case "s:double":
  return (value != null) ? parseFloat(value + "") : 0;
 case "s:datetime":
  if (value == null)
   return null;
  else {
   value = value + "";
   value = value.substring(0,
     (value.lastIndexOf(".") == -1 ? value.length : value
       .lastIndexOf(".")));
   value = value.replace(/T/gi, " ");
   value = value.replace(/-/gi, "/");
   var d = new Date();
   d.setTime(Date.parse(value));
   return d;
  }
 }
}
SOAPClient._getTypesFromWsdl = function(wsdl) {
 var wsdlTypes = new Array();
 // IE
 var ell = wsdl.getElementsByTagName("s:element");
 var useNamedItem = true;
 // MOZ
 if (ell.length == 0) {
  ell = wsdl.getElementsByTagName("element");
  useNamedItem = false;
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < ell.length; i++) {
  if (useNamedItem) {
   if (ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name") != null
     && ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("type") != null)
    wsdlTypes[ell[i].attributes.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue] = ell[i].attributes
      .getNamedItem("type").nodeValue;
  } else {
   if (ell[i].attributes["name"] != null
     && ell[i].attributes["type"] != null)
    wsdlTypes[ell[i].attributes["name"].value] = ell[i].attributes["type"].value;
  }
 }
 return wsdlTypes;
}
SOAPClient._getTypeFromWsdl = function(elementname, wsdlTypes) {
 var type = wsdlTypes[elementname] + "";
 return (type == "undefined") ? "" : type;
}
// private: utils
SOAPClient._getElementsByTagName = function(document, tagName) {
 try {
  // trying to get node omitting any namespaces (latest versions of MSXML.XMLDocument)
  return document.selectNodes(".//*[local-name()=\"" + tagName + "\"]");
 } catch (ex) {
 }
 // old XML parser support
 return document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
}
// private: xmlhttp factory
SOAPClient._getXmlHttp = function() {
 try {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // some versions of Moz do not support the readyState property and the onreadystate event so we patch it!
   if (req.readyState == null) {
    req.readyState = 1;
    req.addEventListener("load", function() {
     req.readyState = 4;
     if (typeof req.onreadystatechange == "function")
      req.onreadystatechange();
    }, false);
   }
   return req;
  }
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
   return new ActiveXObject(SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID());
 } catch (ex) {
 }
 throw new Error("Your browser does not support XmlHttp objects");
}
SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID = function() {
 if (SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid)
  return SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid;
 var progids = [ "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0",
   "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" ];
 var o;
 for (var i = 0; i < progids.length; i++) {
  try {
   o = new ActiveXObject(progids[i]);
   return SOAPClient._getXmlHttpProgID.progid = progids[i];
  } catch (ex) {
  }
  ;
 }
 throw new Error("Could not find an installed XML parser");
}

SOAPClient._toBase64 = function(input) {
 var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
 var output = "";
 var chr1, chr2, chr3;
 var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
 var i = 0;

 do {
  chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
  chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
  chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

  enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
  enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
  enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
  enc4 = chr3 & 63;

  if (isNaN(chr2)) {
   enc3 = enc4 = 64;
  } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
   enc4 = 64;
  }

  output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2)
    + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
 } while (i < input.length);

 return output;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

ERRORS:

1. OPTIONS:mywebserviceURL.403(forbidden)
2. XMLHttpRequest cannot  load mywebserviceURL.Response to preflight request doesn’t  pass access control check :’Acess-Control-Access-Origin’ on the requsted resource. Origin  domain is therefore not allowed access. The response had http status code 403.
3. Uncaught NetworkError:Failed to execute ‘send’ on ‘XMLHttpRequest’. Failed to load mywebserviceURL.

Things I have tried.

I tried setting various headers:

•   “Access-Control-Request-Method” ,”GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS”.

•   “Access-Control-Allow-Origin”, ” * ”

•   “X-Requested-With”,”XMLHttpRequest”

•   “Content-Type”, ”text/xml ; charset utf-8”

•   “Access-Control-Requesst-Header” ,”X-Custom-Header”

Comment: How you are calling the Web Service? Copy the program here

Comment: @Ankushsoni I have added Code

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the server rendering the webservice dos not support [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" parameter have to set on the server side while sending the HTTP response and not on the client side (while sending the request)

Comment: I dont know about server configuration...Is there any way to know if server supports CORS or not?

Comment: the term server I employed is not really accurated, I should say webservice on the server side, as it is, it is not a related to the server configuration but have to specify in the code itself of the webservice. The header of HTTP response send back to the client must specify the parameter "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with value "*". The exact implementation depends on the language used on the sevrer side as example with nodejs would be: response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");

Comment: my previous answer is slightly incorrect, depending on the server, http headers can be setted in the "configuration" as with apache, the following line added in a .htaccess file does the job: Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "\*"